# What is the ‘Gospel of the Grace of God’?

Tags: grace, abraham, covenants, gospel

I just encountered a teaching about ‘The Gospel of Promised Grace to Abraham’ or ‘The Gospel of Grace of God.’ It talks about the everlasting covenant of God to Abraham. I know how the promise of God to Abraham was fulfilled through Jesus, that nations will be blessed through Him and we are the recipient of that promise. Can you help me better understand this subject? What is typically meant by these expressions?

Comment: Unfortunately although the various types of Christians agree on much of what the "Gospel of the Grace of God" means, they do disagree about some of the finer details and more importantly, the required response to them. As such, as well as being a very broad subject to cover, there are aspects that are "primarily-opinion-based" (according to this site's rules, though most of the participants would argue that their version is really true rather than just an opinion). For these reasons, we aren't able to give you a definitive answer to your question here on this site.

Comment: @bruisedreed do you think this might be workable into an overview type question?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I really don't think so - I think it would verge on being too broad even when focusing on just one viewpoint.

Comment: You would probably get much more useful answers to this question if you [edit] and mention _where_ you ran across these phrases. Knowing who said them and in what context might provide significant background information leading to what they meant, otherwise this question will turn around generalities.

Comment: @Caleb I'm not really sure but I think they got the phrase ‘Gospel of the Grace of God’ from Acts 20:24 and then they connect it to God's promise to Abraham.

Comment: Who is "they"? What book are you reading or whose sermons are you listening to? I know where similar phrases could come from Scripture, the question is how are they actually being used.

Comment: @Caleb I heard this teaching from a Bible sharing. A pastor shared to us that we should widen our knowledge and always remember the ‘Gospel of Grace of God’ which is also, according to him, the “Gospel of Promised Grace to Abraham”. He and the other pastors with him didn't give much detail about it, that's why I'm asking this question. I assume they are talking about the announcement of the Gospel in advance to Abraham, and that Gospel should be the same Gospel we should believe today.

Comment: @ProdigalJohn Unfortunately, there are not any past or current Christian authors that can be quoted to be able to answer this question within the rules of this forum. However, I am a former pastor and I believe that I understand your question and could provide you with my opinion of Acts 20:24 and how it relates to the promise to Abraham as I have taught this to my congregation. akberardis@comcast.net if you are interested.